# What is the shape (n_clusters, n_features) referring to? and how to use it

Tags: python, scikit-learn

```
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters = 5, init = ?, random_state = 42)
```

How to define it in my program (n_clusters, n_features)?

I want to define my own centroid rather than 'kmean++' or 'random'

Comment: # Fitting K-Means to the dataset
x = np.array([[15,39],[60,40],[87,27],[60,50],[72,34]])
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters = 5, init =x, random_state = 42) this is write way or wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To initialize your kmeans, you need k points (number of clusters). Each of your point is represented by features, so it produces an array of k points each of dimension d (the number of features).

So KMeans expects here a numpy array with **n_clusters** rows and **n_features** columns containing your specified points for initialization. This is what the shape is referring to.

Of course, it should be consistent with the number of clusters you expect in the first argument (so here, you should have 5 points).

Comment: can i define it in this way its write or wrong     
# Fitting K-Means to the dataset
x = np.array([[15,39],[60,40],[87,27],[60,50],[72,34]])
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters = 5, init =x, random_state = 42)